# Displaying the sidebar on the landing page in ‘docs-only’ mode

Tags: docusaurus

I’m setting up documentation in Docusaurus V2, and have set it up to be ‘docs-only’ by following the instructions in the Docusaurus documentation (setting the routeBasePath and homePageId). That works as expected.

The problem is that when you land on the docs homepage, there is no sidebar. The ‘Next’ button is available at the bottom of the page, and once you use that or any of the top menu bar links to navigate to any other page, the sidebars work perfectly!

What am I missing??

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Please report it on the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you've added that doc page to your `sidebars.js` file

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it turns out that bug was fixed in alpha.56, and I was using .55! It’s working fine now with no other changes made.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug I fixed recently, please upgrade.

Also, remove the file at src/pages/index.js